# Can't run app after deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

After I deploy my nodejs app to heroku. And run the node app.js in console. It's always said " Cannot find module 'serve-index'. Althought I install it in server and local. But nothing happened. It still said cannot find module 'serve-index'